# Keycloak redirection issue behind proxy (Kong)

Tags: nginx, keycloak, kong, redirect-uri

I'm trying to setup a Keycloak instance to handle the users of my webapp. This instance would be, like all others microservices, hidden behind a reverse proxy (Kong, it's a nginx-based proxy).

On my local setup, Kong listens to https://localhost, and keycloak listens to `http://localhost:8082/auth`.
To achieve that, I used several environment variables on my Keycloak container :

```
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=localhost
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_PORT=8082
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false
ENV KC_PROXY=edge
ENV PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
ENV KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_HTTP_PORT=8082
KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/auth
```

The setup of Kong configuration looks fine, and the keycloak endpoints that I need are exposed correctly through Kong (`/realms`, `/js`, `/resources`, `/robots.txt`, like the doc said). Kong handles the TLS connection, and then speaks to all microservices with `HTTP` only, thus `KC_PROXY=edge`. `/admin` is not exposed, I though I could access this locally using `localhost:8082` on the right machine.

If I go to `https://localhost/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration`, I get the configuration. However, Keycloak does not know it's behind Kong, so all endpoints contains `localhost:8082`. That seems normal, since it's how I set it up in the first place.

I tried to add a new `realm` with a different `Frontend URL`, calling it `https://myapp.com`
Now, my openid configuration contains `https://myapp.com:8082/...` everywhere. All the workflows get wrongs URLs.
What did I miss ? I cannot remove this port that I put in the first place, otherwise I will not be able to access the admin console.
I thought I could do something with `KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN`, but unfortunately there is no `KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_PORT`.. or is there ?

Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it's of interest to someone, the solution was actually quite simple. I should not have set the `HOSTNAME` and `HOSTNAME_PORT` in the first place.
`ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false` is mandatory, and also I needed to add a plugin to Kong to tweak the headers :

```
plugins
- name: post-function
  service: keycloak
  config:
    functions:
      - return function()
          if ngx.var.upstream_x_forwarded_port == "8000" then
            ngx.var.upstream_x_forwarded_port = 80
          elseif ngx.var.upstream_x_forwarded_port == "8443" then
            ngx.var.upstream_x_forwarded_port = 443
          end
        end
```

Otherwise, keycloak would have the wrong redirect uri in some cases.